# Can't find isServer in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using `getInitialProps` in `next.js`

This my code:

```
  static getInitialProps( ctx ) {

    console.log(ctx.isServer);
    return{}

}
```

Why can't I find `isServer`?

Comment: [this is not official](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2946)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

`getInitialProps` receives a context object with the following properties:

- `pathname` - path section of URL
- `query` - query string section of URL parsed as an object
- `asPath` - String of the actual path (including the query) shows in the browser
- `req` - HTTP request object (server only)
- `res` - HTTP response object (server only)
- `jsonPageRes` - Fetch Response object (client only)
- `err` - Error object if any error is encountered during the rendering

So the easiest way to check if it is a server to check for req object.

Example

```
static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
  const isServer = !!req;
  return {}
}
```

Here is what next.js maintainers say on [isServer attribute](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2946#issuecomment-329235139)

Hope this help!